# Tab Bar dissapears when I go back

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

Hi i have an application that has a Tab Bar Controller, when I move between tabs it is all good. However, if I move to another View and then press the back button which this is the code inside the back button

```
let viewController: Exercise_Type_ViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Exercise_type") as! Exercise_Type_ViewController
        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

the view and data of the view load correctly but the tab bar doesn't. How can I make the tab bar appear again?

Thanks

Comment: There isn't enough code in your question to answer the question.

Comment: We need code of yours of where you are stuck so we have a starting point to check to.

Comment: Don't present a new viewController to go back.  Call `dismissViewController` or use an unwind segue.

Comment: thats all the code for loading the view, the rest is done in the storyboard. my question is more of how do you segue into a view that has a tabbar? do you go to the tab bar controller? or straight to the view? do you have to add something to the view did load to add the tab bar?

Comment: thanks @vacawama that worked!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the bad English. I had that Problem too. The problem is that you are presenting a single view controller not the tabbarViewController on press of back button so you need to PushViewController when you want to go to other viewController and in other viewController on back  button action **"popViewControllerAnimated"**

**Code in back button action**

```
navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

or

```
self.navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

it will present the last viewController which is pushed in the navigation stack

Hope it helps.  It worked for me.